# Por que tengo error en el codigo al crear el objeto fecha en java?

Tags: java

```
package libro.cap02.fechas;
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class TestFecha {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

{
    System.out.println("Ingrese: (dia mes y año)");

    int dia = scanner.nextInt();
    int mes = scanner.nextInt();
    int año = scanner.nextInt();

    Fecha f1 = new Fecha(dia, mes, año);


        System.out.print ("Ingrese : (dia mes y año)");

        dia = scanner.nextInt();
        mes = scanner.nextInt();
        año = scanner.nextInt();

    Fceha f2 = new Fecha (dia,mes,año);

    System.out.println("Fecha 1 = " +f1);
    System.out.println("Fecha 2 = " +f2);

    if (f1.equals(f2))
     {
          System.out.println("Son iguales");
     }

     else
     {
         System.out.println("Son distintas...");
     }
}}}
```

Comment: Es difícil de saber si no nos pones el error que te da ni el código de la clase Fecha

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Como dice @JaviMollá, ¿qué error da? Aquí tienes un error: `Fceha f2 = new Fecha (dia,mes,año);`, escribiste `Fceha` en vez de `Fecha`.  Si aún así da error, ¿cómo está constituida tu clase `Fecha`?

Answer (score 0):

creo que el error se debe a que esta mal invocada, ya sea por la parte que le hace falta un constructor, o que no tengas métodos para ingresar los datos adecuadamente.

Supongo que la clase "Fecha" es así:

```
public class Fecha {
    private int dia, mes, anio;

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }
}
```

De ser así, tendrías que añadir los valores de la siguiente forma:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fecha f1 = new Fecha();
        f1.setAnio(2018);
        f1.setMes(10);
        f1.setDia(04);

        Fecha f2 = new Fecha();
        f2.setAnio(2018);
        f2.setMes(10);
        f2.setDia(04);

        if (f1.equals(f2)) {
            System.out.println("Son iguales");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Son distintas...");
        }
    }
}
```

Otra forma es añadiendo un costructor a la clase "Fecha":

```
public class Fecha {
    private int dia, mes, anio;

    public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anio) {
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.anio = anio;
    }
}
```

Y cuando es invocada, se ingresan de la siguiente forma:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fecha f3 = new Fecha(04, 10, 2018);
        Fecha f4 = new Fecha(04, 10, 2018);

        if (f3.equals(f4)) {
            System.out.println("Son iguales");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Son distintas...");
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos